# Node.js Mysql: connection failed

Tags: mysql, node.js, connection

I'm trying to connect node.js to mysql and it's failed, I already install mysql. Can anyone help me ?

```
const express    = require("express");
const mysql      = require('mysql');

var app = express();

var mysqlConnection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "******",
    database: "otablo",
});

mysqlConnection.connect((err)=> {
    if(!err)
    {
        console.log("Connected");
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("Connection Failed");
    }
})

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Give us an error message together.

Comment: Could you explain more than 'it failed' what error ? Console.log the error

Comment: What error is it giving you?

Answer (score 1):

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

var app = express();
var mysqlConnection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "****",
    database: "****",
});

mysqlConnection.connect((err)=> {
    if(!err)
    {
        console.log("Connected");
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("Connection Failed");
    }
})

app.listen(3000);
```

Your code is working fine, make sure you have everything installed and the values for the database are right. It worked for me.

Comment: I already install all it need 
{
  "name": "mysql-example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-handlebars": "^3.1.0",
    "mysql": "^2.17.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.19.3"
  }
}

Comment: then maybe there is a problem with your database values. make sure the username, password and the database is right

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, I get the error message: `ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE: Client does not support auth
entication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MyS
QL client`

The solution:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password'
```

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issue. The problem was in password. I tried to use same password that I saw in the tutorial, instead of using my own password that I took for my database during mysql installation process.

Comment: Answer looks a bit simplistif, knowing that the question itself does not give a lot of information about the error itself.